# Detecting early termination of HTTP connection in Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, http, connection, symfony-1.4

I'm interested in using the mark as read method for emails and in-app notifications as specified [here](https://gist.github.com/4235649?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=social&utm_content=18911ef9-5f82-40ca-9f4a-afb1cb9ba98e)

I'm using Symfony 1.4 and I can't find anything within `sfContext` or `sfWebRequest` that can be used to detect if the connection has been terminated. Is there anyway to do this within the Symfony framework?

Would I be able to use the PHP functions `connection_status()` or `connection_aborted()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a typical PHP script, the script execution will stop at the next tickable event after the user terminates a connection.

Because of this, you shouldn't need to really do anything to get this to work (unless you have changed this setting in your php.ini) or someone has set the `ignore_user_abort` flag.

But, if you want to be safe, you could do the following:

```
<?php

// Whatever you need here
sleep(5);

if (false == connection_aborted()) {
    // Mark the notification as read
}
```